# iOS Mobile Device Management and Configuration Profiles

Tags: ios, mdm, configuration-profile

I have two questions about iOS Mobile Device Management Server and Configuration Profiles. I didn't found anything about this issues and I hope you can help me.

We are using a Third Party MDM server where we are registering our devices to have control of the apps that are running on our organization

When we deliver the Configuration Profile over the MDM server on a freshly restored device we are seeing that some apps are not being hidden (like Facebook, Whatsapp and some others). They only hide if we reinstall or update that apps, are there some kind of configuration that we can make to block these apps?

The second question is about the icon arrangement before we uninstall the Configuration Profile. Once the profile was removed we notice that the icons are rearranged in a new order that doesn't match the old arrangement (before the blocking). Are there any action that we can do to keep the order?